# How to match column a and column b from same table in BigQuery on substring match

Tags: string, google-bigquery

I'm using #standardSQL BigQuery. I tried to use LIKE but couldn't get the matching to occur.

I have the table below, I am trying to write a query in BigQuery where if column A is contained in Column B then I want an output column C with the string from Column A OR '1'. In the case, that there is no match between Column A and Column B then I would want Column B OR '0' in the output Column C.

```
id    |    Column A   |   Column B
1     |    John    |    Alex, John
3     |    Cerci   |    Cerci  
5     |    Mike   |    Mike 
2     |    Simi    |    Expatri  
6     |    Hazel    |    Expatri, Hazel  
4     |    Bald   |    Hair
7     |    Cam   |    Ambrose, Cam
```

What I would ideally want

```
id    |    Column A   |   Column B  | **Column C**
1     |    John    |    Alex, John | John
3     |    Cerci   |    Cerci  | Cerci
5     |    Mike   |    Mike | Mike
2     |    Simi    |    Expatri  | Expatri
6     |    Hazel    |    Expatri, Hazel  | Hazel
4     |    Bald   |    Hair | Hair
7     |    Cam   |    Ambrose, Cam | Cam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    id,
    A,
    B,
    CASE WHEN B LIKE '%' || A || '%' THEN A ELSE B END AS C
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(Column_B, Column_A), Column_A, Column_B) AS Column_C
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If applied to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  Column_A    Column_B        Column_C     
1   1   John        Alex, John      John     
2   3   Cerci       Cerci           Cerci    
3   5   Mike        Mike            Mike     
4   2   Simi        Expatri         Expatri  
5   6   Hazel       Expatri, Hazel  Hazel    
6   4   Bald        Hair            Hair     
7   7   Cam         Ambrose, Cam    Cam
```